# SlickGrid crashes browser when selecting a huge range of rows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, slickgrid

I have been looking for data grids, written in JavaScript that can handle virtualization and present millions of rows, for the users with great performance.

Stumbled on SlickGrid and tried it out. It worked great until I tried to select a huge range of rows before the browser crashed. Googled and found this post with exactly the same problem: [SlickGrid/issues/778](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/778).

Is there any fix or other grid that can virtualize millions of rows with full keyboard support and can handle selections without browser crashing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my response on the GitHub issue - https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/issues/778#issuecomment-26183257.